# First call not passing object to endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have an API where I'm using Node/Express/Mongoose where I'm trying to call a function to grab IDs for a number of fields to populate my main function, which creates a profile card for a particular user.

I'm passing the 'owner_id' to my Profile method. Then I want to reference the returned fields in my main function, which is the Cards document.

But when I try to reference the results of the first call, I get an error saying the fields are undefined.

Here is my code:

```
router.route('/')

// CREATE INITIAL PROFILE AND ADD EMAILS, ADDRESSES, PHONES AND BUSINESSES ONE-BY-ONE
.post(function( req, res ){

  Profile.findOne({'owner_id': req.body.ownerId}, (err, profile) => {

  })


  var card = new Card();

  card.owner_id = req.body.ownerId;
  card.card_name = req.body.card_name;
  card.card_subtitle = req.body.card_subtitle;
  card.card_type = req.body.card_type;
  card.card_color = req.body.card_color;

  card.first_name.item = req.body.first_name ;
  card.first_name._id = profile.first_name._id;

  card.last_name.item = req.body.last_name;
  card.last_name._id = profile.last_name._id;

  card.company = req.body.company;
  card.title = req.body.title;

  card.initial.item = req.body.initial ;
  card.initial._id = profile.initial._id;

  card.birthday.item = req.body.birthday ;
  card.birthday._id = profile.birthday._id;

  card.highschool.item = req.body.highschool;
  card.highschool._id = profile.highschool._id;

  card.college.item = req.body.college ;
  card.college._id = profile.college._id;

  card.facebook.item = req.body.facebook;
  card.facebook._id = profile.facebook._id;

  card.linkedin.item = req.body.linkedin ;
  card.linkedin._id = profile.linkedin._id;

  card.linkedin_bus.item = req.body.linkedin_bus ;
  card.linkedin_bus._id = profile.linkedin_bus._id;

  card.twitter.item = req.body.twitter ;
  card.twitter._id = profile.twitter._id;

  card.google.item = req.body.google ;
  card.google._id = profile.google._id;

  card.pinterest.item = req.body.pinterest;
  card.pinterest._id = profile.pinterest._id;

  card.user_image.item = req.body.user_image;
  card.user_image._id = profile.user_image._id;


  card.phones = req.body.phones;
  card.emails = req.body.emails;
  card.addresses = req.body.addresses;
  card.businesses = req.body.businesses;


  card.save(function(err){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);
    res.send({message:'Card has been added'});
  });



});
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The general problem

`Profile.findOne` is an asynchronous call. This basically means that it needs some time to get the profile. When it gets the profile, it will get passed to the callback function passed as a second parameter, and that callback function be executed.

Anything you run right after the `Profile.findOne()` call will be executed **before** the callback function. This is a really common issue with javascript, and you can get more insight about this [in this really famous SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

#### The solution

In your case, you can just move all your code that needs the `profile` to the callback function:

```
Profile.findOne({'owner_id': req.body.ownerId}, (err, profile) => {
  //this is the body of the callback function. It will be called some time after `findOne` is called.
  var card = new Card();

  card.owner_id = req.body.ownerId;
  card.card_name = req.body.card_name;
  card.card_subtitle = req.body.card_subtitle;
  card.card_type = req.body.card_type;
  card.card_color = req.body.card_color;

  card.first_name.item = req.body.first_name ;
  card.first_name._id = profile.first_name._id;

  card.last_name.item = req.body.last_name;
  card.last_name._id = profile.last_name._id;

  card.company = req.body.company;
  card.title = req.body.title;

  card.initial.item = req.body.initial ;
  card.initial._id = profile.initial._id;

  card.birthday.item = req.body.birthday ;
  card.birthday._id = profile.birthday._id;

  card.highschool.item = req.body.highschool;
  card.highschool._id = profile.highschool._id;

  card.college.item = req.body.college ;
  card.college._id = profile.college._id;

  card.facebook.item = req.body.facebook;
  card.facebook._id = profile.facebook._id;

  card.linkedin.item = req.body.linkedin ;
  card.linkedin._id = profile.linkedin._id;

  card.linkedin_bus.item = req.body.linkedin_bus ;
  card.linkedin_bus._id = profile.linkedin_bus._id;

  card.twitter.item = req.body.twitter ;
  card.twitter._id = profile.twitter._id;

  card.google.item = req.body.google ;
  card.google._id = profile.google._id;

  card.pinterest.item = req.body.pinterest;
  card.pinterest._id = profile.pinterest._id;

  card.user_image.item = req.body.user_image;
  card.user_image._id = profile.user_image._id;


  card.phones = req.body.phones;
  card.emails = req.body.emails;
  card.addresses = req.body.addresses;
  card.businesses = req.body.businesses;


  card.save(function(err){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);
    res.send({message:'Card has been added'});
  });
});
console.log(profile); // now, however, this line is executed immediately. At this point, profile is not even
// retrieved from the database. Even if the database call was somehow instant, here `profile` is not even in the scope.
```